# Script not working when called externally

Tags: bash, scripts

I use a simple script to create .mp3s from .mp4 files:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in *.mp4
do
ffmpeg -i "$i" -ab 128k "${i%mp4}mp3"
done
```

The script runs fine when run from the desktop or called via the terminal. When the script is called from an external script however, it fails to run, returning

> "*.mp4: No Such File or Directory".

I suspect the issue is with shell expansion, but can't wrap my head around how to fix it in this situation.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are using a relative path, where your script is looking for the `.mp4` files in the current directory i.e. the directory from where the script is being run, and finding that no such `.mp4` file exists, then it looks for a literal `*.mp4` file (assuming `nullglob`/`failglob` is not set, which is the default), and that file does not exist too, hence the error message `*.mp4: No Such File or Directory`.

You should use absolute path instead:

```
for i in /directory/*.mp4; do ...; done
```

Replace `/directory/` with the actual directory path; if you want you can take the directory name as first argument too:

```
for i in "$1"/*.mp4; do ...; done
```

You can use absolute or relative path here, but again absolute path is always the safer option.

Now call the executable script in usual manner:

```
/path/to/script.sh /directory
```

From the script directory:

```
./script.sh /directory
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Was about to tell you I had already tried that unsuccessfully, but then noticed I'd capitalized the "H" in "/home" first time through. The passing of the path as argument was particularly useful. Cheers.

Comment: Where "hence the error message" actually means: since the shell is unable to match `*.mp4` to any file it consider it as a literal file name and tries to open the file called `*.mp4` (which is a valid file name) and fails because you have no file called `*.mp4` in the current directory.  Someone could think that `*.mp4` always expand to the list of matching filenames, which could be empty (and in that case the `for` loop would do nothing, but no errors would be raised), this is not the case: `*.mp4` always expands to something.

Comment: @Bakuriu Whereas this is true in this case (or default in `bash`) but not always; look at `nullglob`/`failglob`.

Comment: Were I went wrong is thinking the '*' was just for the filename, rather than the combination of path AND filename. live and learn :)